Error about starting values fitting glm family=gamma in R
I ran a longitudinal pre-post study where, I exposed the participants to an intervention designed to increase their pro-climate behaviors. I recorded their initial pro-climate behaviors (A_meanBehavior) and their final pro-climate behaviors (B_meanBehavior). I now want to predict their final behavior using some predictors, among which their initial behavior.
The B_meanBehavior data is very skewed, so I picked family=Gamma. Here is the model:
model = glm(B_meanBehavior ~  A_meanBehavior + A_Emotional_Engagement + A_Self_Efficacy +  A_Collective_Efficacy + A_Theory_of_Change + A_Cognitive_Alternatives + A_Perceived_Behavioral_Control + A_Self_Identity + A_Collective_Identity + A_Appraisal + A_Faith_Institutions + deltaEE + deltaSE + deltaCE + deltaTOC + deltaCA + deltaPBC + deltaSI + deltaCI + deltaA + deltaFI, family = Gamma,  data=EMA_PSY)
I keep getting the following error, and I don't understand what it means:
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values. In addition: Warning message: In log(ifelse(y == 0, 1, y/mu)) : NaNs produced
Which starting values should I supply? I tried adding "start = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)" as a specification in the model, but to be honest I am not sure whether this makes sense.
Here is the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k8vQsB8ioibYzR3jlqT47G90aEJcGuX0/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100461937272544737530&rtpof=true&sd=true
Thank you for your help!

Is your dependent variable "B_meanBehavior" supposed to have commas or decimals? In any case, I assume that 0,00 should correspond to 0, and the support of the Gamma is the positive reals. Hence the error.

Thanks for your reply! Actually there are no 0 values, nor 0,00 (I transformed 0 values into 0,0000001 in order to be able to use family=Gamma).

You have 66 observations and are trying to fit 22 coefficients. Forget it. You would need a dataset that is several orders of magnitude larger to fit such a complex model.

Oh I see, thank you Roland for your help with this, this makes sense. However, I get this same error even when I go down to 10 coefficients (taking out all the predictors starting with "A" and only keeping the ones starting with "delta"). Is it still too many coefficients?

Oh, nvm sorry, it worked now with the 10 coefficients!
